# Haskell: Define product with foldr

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to define `product` with `foldr`:

I could do it with:

`new_product xs = foldr (*) 1 xs`

but not:

`new_product = foldr (*) 1`

or:

`new_product = \xs -> foldr (*) 1 xs`

Both definition produce the same error:

> No instance for (Foldable t0) arising from a use of ‘folder’
>
> The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
>
> Relevant bindings include
>
> new_product :: t0 Integer -> Integer

Is it some kind of type error?

How could I fix it?

Comment: The claim "this question is already answered by 'What is the monomorphism restriction'?" is simply false and degrading to the user.

Answer (score 3):

This is the [Monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) at work. The solution is to add a type signature:

```
new_product :: (Foldable t, Num b) => t b -> b
new_product = foldr (*) 1
```

---

Essentially, the problem here is that unless you are in GHCi (where this is disabled) Haskell refuses to infer a polymorphic type signature unless you explicitly have variables for the function. As a concrete example:

```
f x = ...      -- `f` can infer polymorphic type (in `x`) 
f = \x -> ...  -- `f` infers a monomorphic type
```

In your case, `f` is `new_product` and `x` is `xs`. When you have the point-free style, Haskell attempts to infer a monomorphic signature for `new_product` and fails because it can't figure out which `Foldable` instance to choose (based on `foldr`). On the other hand, when you include the `xs`, Haskell is no longer bound to infer a monomorphic signature, hence everything works.

There is reason to this madness: the point is that when you write something like `f = ...` it is natural to assume that `f` only gets evaluated once. Yet, unless we force `f` to be monomorphic, that isn't necessarily the case.

To use an example related to your function: suppose that I infer that `p = num_product [1..1000]` has type `Num a => a` (the most general type in this case), then using `p :: Int` and `p :: Integer` will cause us to evaluate `p` at least twice.

Haskell has therefore decided not to *generalize* top-level bindings: you only infer polymorphic signatures for functions that have their variables explicit (ie. on the left hand side of the equal). That said, if you wish to explicitly write a polymorphic type signature, you are free to do so.

Comment: But I didn't specify type at the first definition. Why does is work if a type signature is required?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that you can, y’know, just *turn the monomorphism restriction off* if you so desire with the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` language pragma.

Comment: The monomorphism restriction only functions at the top level; it does not affect `let` bindings. The monomorphism restriction is rarely actually useful, and is especially unlikely to be useful if you compile your code with optimizations enabled; if it confuses you, turn it off.